# Discrepancy between rep on summary tab and reputation tab

Tags: bug, reputation

I received an accept on an answer to a question that is closed today.
The summary tab says +25 for that accept, the reputation tab says +15 for the accept.

I assume that the +15 is right since I was on 900, and now I'm on 915, however, I thought I'd highlight the discrepancy. I have seen other cases where there is a delay in the gui, but this seems to be something different?

Here's a screenshot:

[image: rep]

Comment: You also got one upvote, which is being lumped together on one line in the top box, but the bottom box shows the accept on a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

On the summary, all reputation from the post is summed up. That's with upvotes etc. On the reputation tab, you now only see the accept. But further down, you see your upvote as well.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a delay thing, though. The number is there in both places, it's just the wrong number. I think maybe the summary page doesn't take into account the fact that the question was closed, and so it sees it as 25, but the reputation page takes the accept as a closed question accept and so it's 15. It might just be a matter of telling the summary page that closed accepts are 15, not 25.

Comment: Sorry, re-read and updated my answer.

Comment: yes, I thought of the sum thing too, but the green highlight indicates an accept. I've expanded both reps completely so both are data from a single action (demonstrated by the green box). I don't get that much rep where keeping track is that difficult.

Comment: In the summary (25) there is the sum of the accept (15) and one upvote (10). On the expanded view you can see the accept and the upvote separated, on the summary you only see the reputation per post: the sum.

Comment: I see what you're saying. My understanding was that the summary only was for "recent" occurrences? Since the #2 on the summary list occurred 3 days after the upvote, it's easy to assume that #1 on the summary list contains data that occurred most recently, and isn't a combination of today and 5 days ago. This is quite counter-intuitive, to be honest.

Comment: I don't use the summary tab but can't feel with you it's counter-intuitive. You could make a new meta-question with a `feature-request`